# Upload and parse an Excel file in a Backbone.js app with Rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, file-upload, backbone.js

There is a lot of information in the title of the question !

I'm aware of Rails gems to upload files, parse Excel, etc. but I would like to know which solution will work nice in a Backbone app (that is, I don't want to reload the page during the upload). Is there a Backbone extension for that ?

The story is: the user wants to upload an Excel file, she browses her filesystem, selects the file, click "upload"... and then the Backbone app shows the content of the file (I don't need to store the file on the server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i dont think there is any backbone extension for that :) What you need is some upload extension like uploadify of http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ . You will bind the
success method to uploader and then you can do anything with the data returned from server.